# How can I join 3 tables and output all three together joined in web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

model:

```
# coding: utf8
db.define_table('dept',
                Field('name',unique=True,label='Department Name'),
                format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('course',
                Field('dept_id','reference dept'),
                Field('name',unique=True,label='Course Name'),
            format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('files',
                Field('course_id', 'reference course'),
                Field('documentx','upload'))
```

controller:

```
def show_doc():
    rows = db( db.course.id == db.files.course_id , db.dept.id==db.course.dept_id).select()
    return rows
```

What I am trying to do is to join the department table "dept" with the "course" table and the "course" table with the "files" table. So when outputting it shows a table with department with course and files all together. The solution doesn't work. It only creates a join between the "course" table and the "files" table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Logical-operators), it should be:

```
db((db.course.id == db.files.course_id) & (db.dept.id==db.course.dept_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you can simply select all your files :

```
def show_doc():
    rows = db(db.files.documentx).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

Then, in your view "**show_doc.html**" you can access to the linked fields :

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{for row in rows:}}
    <div>Department : {{=row.course_id.dept_id.name}} Course : {{=row.course_id.name}}</div>
    {{if row.documentx:}}
        <div><a href={{=URL('default', 'download', args=row.documentx)}}>Download file</a></div>
    {{pass}}
    <hr>
{{pass}}
```

Comment: This is not the best approach if there are many records, as the recursive selects above result in two additional queries for every record in db.files.

Comment: @Loïc how can i output the name of the file instead of text "Download" <div><a href={{=URL('default', 'download', args=row.files.documentx)}}>{{=row.files.documentx.name}}</a></div> 
is the name stored as some filed hidden as id field?

Comment: You can store the original filename in the model (http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Storing-the-original-filename) but I often prefer adding a "title" field : Field('title', unique=True)