# output the name of file stored in table in upload filed?

Tags: python, web2py

model :

```
db.define_table('files',
                Field('course_id', 'reference course'),
                Field('documentx_filename',unique=True),
                Field('documentx','upload'))
```

controller:

```
def show_doc():
    rows = db( (db.course.id == db.files.course_id) & (db.dept.id==db.course.dept_id) ).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)

def create_doc():
    form = SQLFORM(db.files).process(next=URL('show_doc'))
    if request.vars.documentx != None:
        form.vars.documentx_filename = request.vars.documentx.filename
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'form accepted'
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else :
        response.flash = 'something still went wrong'
    return dict(form = form)
```

view file for show_doc:

```
<div><a href={{=URL('default', 'download', args=row.files.documentx)}}> file = {{=row.files.documentx_filename}}</a></div>
<br />
{{pass}}
```

now if I put the file name in the field "documentx_filename" then the file name is shown.

But if I don't put the name in the field "documentx_filename" and leave it empty but upload a file.
It should copy the name of the file uploaded as in controller create_doc I put the if statement but it doest do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the original filename in the model (http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Storing-the-original-filename)

But, assuming you have the same model as in this post : [How can I join 3 tables and output all three together joined in web2py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697034/how-can-i-join-3-tables-and-output-all-three-together-joined-in-web2py) 
I would add a "title" field in the model definition :

```
db.define_table('files',
                Field('title', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
                Field('course_id', 'reference course'),
                Field('documentx','upload'))
```

Then, in your view you can write :

```
{{for row in rows:}}
    <div><a href={{=URL('default', 'download', args=row.files.documentx)}}>row.files.title</a></div>
{{pass}}
```

Comment: i edited the question and put some more info. Now I can show the file name if we fill the field but it doest copy the filename from file if the field is left empty can you take a look.